# Are there any performance/build size advantage of using angularised port of jquery/java-script libraries?

Tags: angular

I am working in a project where I am using multiple third-party libraries like:

- `Smart table`
- `HandsonTable`
- `Codemirror`
- `Bootstrap`/`ngx-bootstrap`
- `Highcharts`

I started my project with angularized versions of these libraries. However, I won't say it was a good experience. Most of these angularized libraries have poor documentation (except `ngx-bootstrap`), more open issues and some missing features as well. Original libraries have more examples and Stackoverflow QnAs.

Therefore, I have started using original jquery/java-script libraries. One of the problems with that is obviously, my code won't look like angular code and also I will have to use `Ngzone.run()` for change detection. The advantage is I can use CDNs and defer script download.

**Are there any other reasons to use angularised port of these libraries?** Maybe related to build size or performance?

Answer (score 0):

From my development experience, we prefer Angular version of Third party library which is optimized for Angular and we don't want to add extra codes like trigger CD manually, Declare Const Variable etc.

If you think the Angular version of third party library is outdated, doesn't support the features you require. You can opt for Javascript version. Its up to you to choose and based on ur needs.

Regarding Bundle Size, Webpack will include only the Modules, Components, Templates you accessed. It will remove unused code on Tree Shaking and Dead Code Elimination. Regarding Size we don't have much difference.